Use of 'static options:{}' not possible with typescript in Shopware
I'm currently using typescript in Shopware (which is supported)
The static keyword is a reserved keyword in Typescript. However so it is in Shopware. For example in a Shopware javascript plugin you could have something like this:
export default class CheckoutPhoneNumberPlugin extends Plugin {
static options = {
    billingPhoneNumberSelector: '#billingAddressAddressPhoneNumber',
    shippingPhoneNumberSelector: '#shippingAddressAddressPhoneNumber'
};

init() {
    this._billingPhoneNumber = document.querySelector(this.options.billingPhoneNumberSelector);
    this._shippingPhoneNumber = document.querySelector(this.options.shippingPhoneNumberSelector);

    this._registerEvents();
}
...

In the compile proces of javascript in Shopware the static keyword is required for the use of options like you see in the example.
But if you're using typescript, using static will make options no longer an instance of the class. So then you can't call this.options anymore, because it doesn't belong to this.
How to deal with this situation?

I don't know anything about shopware, but the static keyword is part of modern JavaScript, not just TypeScript. Static members aren't instance members in JavaScript.  Where is the documentation for shopware's use of static?

I can't find documentation about the use of static in Shopware. But this is the Plugin class that I extend -> Shopware Repo
I found someone pointing me to how Shopware uses this static options themselves in typescript Shopware repo
So apparently I need to use public static options = {} But I don't understand why.

So then static is not a "keyword" of shopware. It's just using static and it looks like maybe you thought they were instance properties instead of class properties. For class statics just write CheckoutPhoneNumberPlugin.options instead of this.options. Does anything go wrong if you do that?

Using CheckoutPhoneNumberPlugin.options does work. So I guess this is the way to do it. But I would prefer using this as it is more logical since the values are used only in the class itself. But because of the plugin merge proces of Shopware I have to use static -> _mergeOptions()

"I would prefer" That's fine that you prefer this, but that's not what static means. Possibly you could use this.constructor.options although that will fail to type check in TS because of ms/TS#3841. But regardless: this question has a false premise, and has essentially nothing to do with shopware or even TypeScript. It's just a misconception about what static means in JavaScript. How shall we proceed with this question? Do you want to [edit] to fix/clarify? Delete the question? Get an answer that explains static?
